# Two Apple Developer Accounts, One App

Tags: apple-id, app-store-connect, developer-program

Backgrounder, we have two (2) Apple Developer Accounts, one account is being used by development team and another is for production deployment and distribution. I know that this is not the best practice, but have to do it (for the meantime) as to comply to internal company policies.

My question is can I submit the same app using two (2) different Apple Developer accounts? The first submission objective is to resolve any issues that might arise prior to production distribution.

Comment: Try to make first submission from the production account, just don't release it. You will save yourself from troubles of changing app ids later (deletion of the app and resubmitting it again), or with other issues when you transfer the app (as far as I remember app should be live in order to be transferred).

Answer (score 2):

This question will likely only attract opinions; only [Apple can answer your question](https://developer.apple.com/contact/) with any authority. You should consider e-mailing or phoning Apple's developer team before embarking too far.

### No Duplicate Apps Allowed

Note that Apple will not accept duplicate applications in the store. You may be able to delete the developer app and re-submit to the production account. I suspect a new bundle identifier would still be needed. You would also be exposed to another review.

## Transfer Before Publishing

Knowing that, have you considered submitting the application to completion using the development account and then [transferring the application](https://developer.apple.com/support/account/) to your distribution account?

> #### Can I transfer my app to another account?
>
> Yes. Use iTunes Connect to transfer qualifying apps to another account in case of an acquisition, asset purchase, or other similar situation. When you transfer an app, it will remain available on the App Store or Mac App Store, all ratings and reviews will carry over, and users will continue to have access to future updates. To learn more about transferring apps, sign in to iTunes Connect.

- The submitted application can remain unpublished until after the transfer.
- Using [some iCloud features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17284665/) will prevent the application from transferring.